# Grammar: Should the sentence say, "my sister or I" or "my sister or me"?

Tags: grammar

I read the following sentence, "My mother won't put up with my sister or I swearing." My question is, should the sentence say, "my sister or I" or "my sister or me"?

Comment: Take your sister out of the picture.  Which word would you use?

Answer (score 3):

"I" is definitely wrong. You wouldn't say "My mother won't put up with I swearing" either. However, there are still two possible correct wordings: Either using "my" or using "me"

> My mother won't put up with my sister or me swearing.

meaning she won't put up with us [when we swear].

> My mother won't put up with my sister's or my swearing.

meaning she won't put up with our swearing.

The difference in meaning is negligible and mainly syntactical.

Comment: Hooray for "... my sister's or my swearing," a construction that is 100% correct and 99% underused. Although this construction is also 98% unfamiliar it hardly ever causes a ripple in conversation if the speaker's tone of voice casually treats it as 100% normal

Answer (score 0):

I never heard such a sentence: *My mother won't put up with my sister or I swearing*. Even though it exists, since you read it, it sounds weird to me.

I think that the sentence *My mother won't put up with my sister or me swearing* is correct, because:

- there's *with* in the sentence that is a preposition that doesn't support the personal pronoun *I*.
- *My sister and me* are the object of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend with me. I think the general rule is prepositions such as with are followed by object pronouns ( me, you, him, her, us and them )

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to say it would be *me*.

Consider these alternatives:

> My mother won't put up with us swearing.
>
> My mother wont' put up with we searing.

It's obvious to any native ear that we would say "with us swearing" instead of "with we swearing."  *Us* is used when something is an object.  *We* is used when something is a subject.  In this sentence, *us* is receiving the action of what mother won't put up with, making it an object and not a subject.

Translated into your sentence, you would also use the object *me* as opposed to the subject *I*.  So the sentence becomes:

> "My mother won't put up with my sister and me swearing.